# radio button not visible in a HorizontalFieldManager in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, radio-button

I am working on a blackberry application which includes radio button controls.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hr = new HorizontalFieldManager();
setTitle("UI Component Sample"); 
RadioButtonGroup rbg = new RadioButtonGroup();
RadioButtonField r1 = new RadioButtonField("Option 1",rbg,true); 
RadioButtonField r2 = new RadioButtonField("Option 2",rbg,false);
hr.add(r1);
hr.add(r2);
add(hr);
```

Working with this code I can see my both radio buttons in curve device but when I install my app in Torch device, only 1st radio button is visible on the screen.
Getting problem in showing one radio group in a horizontal field.
It works when i use a vertical field for a group.

And Horizontal and vertical both works when i works on curve device.

Please suggest what type of bus or problem this is.

[image: We can see only one radio button is visible]

[image]

Comment: Get this problem solved with the Great help pf RUPAK, The main couse of this problem is the DEVICE RESOLUTION OF TORCH AND CURVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS 6, `RadioButtonField` causes some problem regarding its width. Overriding the `layout(int, int)` method may solve your problem. Try following code.

```java
RadioButtonGroup rbg = new RadioButtonGroup();

RadioButtonField rbf = new RadioButtonField("Label", rbg, true) {
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        super.layout(getPreferredWidth(), height);
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello Rupak, Thanx for providing me quick fix, but the problem is not the software version, THIS RADIO BUTTON PROBLEM IS ARISING DUE TO DEVICE RESOLTION, IN TORCH AND CURVE THERE IS A GREAT DIFFERENCE IN RESOLUTION. I DID CONFIRM THAT.:)